# Bash Roundcube Script silent

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to add the following line into a bash script:

```
bin/installto.sh /var/www/mail/rc >/dev/null 2>&1
```

There should be no output, but the upgrade installer requires a yes confirmation:

```
~/roundcubemail-1.2.1# bin/installto.sh /var/www/mail/rc
Upgrading from 1.1.3. Do you want to continue? (y/N)
```

Is there any way to have a silent upgrade with an auto yes confirmation like `apt-get upgrade -y`

Best regards, Aeris

Edit:

I didnt knew the expect command until now 
My script:

> cd roundcubemail-1.2.1 >/dev/null 2>&1
>       expect -c 'bin/installto.sh /var/www/mail/rc >/dev/null 2>&1'
>       expect "Do you want to continue? (y/N)"
>       send "y"
>       interact
>       rm -r /root/roundcubemail-1.2.1/  >/dev/null 2>&1
>       [...]

---> result

> "bin/installto.sh /var/www/mail/rc"
>   couldn't read file "Do you want to continue? (y/N)": no such file or directory
>   /root/update.sh: Zeile 104: send: command not found.
>   /root/update.sh: Zeile 105: interact: command not found.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know expect command?

```
expect -c 'bin/installto.sh /var/www/mail/rc >/dev/null 2>&1'
expect "Do you want to continue? (y/N)"
send "y\n"
interact
```

Comment: Is there any another solution?

The expect command doesn't work -> see Main Post Edit